# I need to know why this jquery only passes 2 out of 3 values to the php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having a very confusing situation here:

My jquery is:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "setSession.php?variable=" + "Invoicenumber" + "&value=" + value + "&test=" + value , true);
xmlhttp.send()
```

Now, if I remove `+ "&test=" + value` from the code it works and submits and passes the values great, but as soon as I add it back in I only get the first 2 values passed but not the third.  I am sure I am missing something completely obvious here but can not see it for the life of me.  Can anyone see whats going wrong here?

Comment: What's the value of `value`?

Comment: @watery Value is defined in ther line before this snippet starts as so     var value = $("#invnum").val()   it is a good value as it passes the first time into &value

Comment: This is likely a plain javascript problem; I suspect that the concatenation of the constant strings and the value of `value` could end up in something that is causing trouble.

Comment: I thought something like that but if I remove the second value and replace it with a number say 10 for instance it still don't go through.

Comment: When you say that the first 2 values are passed but not the third, does that mean that there is no difference at all between not having test in there (and so only getting the first 2 values) and having it?

Comment: @JamesWaddington yes absolutely that is what is happening it is like the third value pair is not even there. (If I remove '+ "&test=" + value' altogether I get the same results as with it. I'm so confused here

Comment: Two quick things I would check - try console.log("setSession.php?variable=" + "Invoicenumber" + "&value=" + value + "&test=" + value ) . check that it looks like you expect it to and try visiting it directly in your browser (with the base url of course). Secondly check setSession.php - often a small mistake can mean you're not reading the values quite like you expect.

Comment: @JamesWaddington  Oh my gosh!!!!!  I feel like a dunce I was assigning  a vaiable in setSession.php using $SESSION['test] and NOT $_SESSION['test] !  ARGH!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Yep they're always the most annoying ones to find!

Comment: wouldn't be that I might be so arrogant to overlook the obvious.... nah Thanks again :)